# How to compare Pandas DataFrame Column value to multilevel index?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my sample DataFrame called `df_output` with Multilevel index.

```
City Name   Threshold          Temp    
Atlanta        86      0       87      
                       1       86      
                       2       85       
                       3       89   
Chicago       90       0       92
                       1       90
                       2       85
                       3       65
```

I am trying to create a new column that indicates whether the value in `Temp` column is greater than the value in Threshold or not.

I tried the following:

```
df_output["Temp > Threshold"] = df_output["Temp"] > df_output.index.get_level_values('Threshold')
```

Which returned True for all the rows. How do I compare the value in `Temp` Column with the corresponding value in the `Threshold` index?

**EDIT:** The logic above is correct, my program was returning `True` for all the rows because the `dtype` of the `Temp` column was `object` and the `Threshold` index was an `int`, so the comparison was returning wonky results.

Comment: can you post the contents of df_output.index as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution works fine. I suggest the problem lies in how your index is defined. Below is an example of how you can explicitly set your index and what `df.index` should look like once you have successfully defined a `MultiIndex`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'City Name': ['Atlanta']*4 + ['Chicago']*4,
                   'Threshold': [86]*4 + [90]*4,
                   'Temp': [87, 86, 85, 89, 92, 90, 85, 65]})

df = df.set_index(['City Name', 'Threshold'])

df['Temp>Threshold'] = df['Temp'] > df.index.get_level_values('Threshold')

print(df)

                     Temp  Temp>Threshold
City Name Threshold                      
Atlanta   86           87            True
          86           86           False
          86           85           False
          86           89            True
Chicago   90           92            True
          90           90           False
          90           85           False
          90           65           False

print(df.index)

MultiIndex(levels=[['Atlanta', 'Chicago'], [86, 90]],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]],
           names=['City Name', 'Threshold'])
```

Comment: how can you be sure that the multiindex is `[City Name, Threshold]`

Comment: @Poppinyoshi, I can't, which is why I'm working backwards to show OP what `MultiIndex` he should have for his logic to work.

Comment: ok cool, that's why I asked OP to post his `df_output.index`, I thought then a solution could be built. I will also try working backwards for other problems as you have here.

Comment: My code didn't work because the datatype of the Temp column was object, and the comparison was yielding incorrect values. But your solution worked

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use `eval` as it will allow you to utilize names of index levels alongside column names.

### in-line

```
df.assign(gt_thresh=df.eval("Temp > Threshold"))

                     Temp  gt_thresh
City Name Threshold                 
Atlanta   86           87       True
          86           86      False
          86           85      False
          86           89       True
Chicago   90           92       True
          90           90      False
          90           85      False
          90           65      False
```

---

### in-place

```
df[“gt_thresh”] = df.eval("Temp > Threshold")
```